# Access Forms - New Field opens if another field is selected

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if it were possible to have a field shown or active if another previous field is selected.

For example, if I have a `Status` field and then choose `Inactive` then I would like another field to show for `Inactive Date`

Thanks

Comment: You could have a control on a form become visible if the `Status` for the record is `Inactive`.  But a field in a table - the table either contains the `InactiveDate` field or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say, you have `checkbox` for status and `textbox` to capture date on your form. 
 `AfterUpdate` event gets triggered when control value changes and you can enable/disable other controls here.

```
Private Sub chkStatus_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.chkStatus Then
        Me.txtDate.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.txtDate.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**To enable/disable textbox on dropdown change using VBA**

```
Private Sub cmbStatus_Change()

    If Nz(Me.cmbStatus, "") = "Active" Then
         Me.txtDate.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Nz(Me.cmbStatus, "") = "InActive" Then
         Me.txtDate.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Using Macro builder - without VBA**

[image]

Comment: What if I have a dropdown (not checkbox)? If I had one field from the dropbox selected, would that work to make the textbox appear? Also, would I just had this VBA?